# Angular and masonry work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, masonry

I do not get masonry working within a ng-repeat.

I try to add a class the masonry-container, and inside of my ng-repeat I use the class masonry-item.

In my js i use those two classes, my js file gets loaded like:
-jquery
-masonry
-myfile

1. HTML)

`<div class="masonry-container" >
    <div ng-repeat="link in links">
        <div class="masonry-item col-sm-4">
            <div class="jumbotron">
                <div>
                    {{link.title}}
                </div>
                <div>
                   {{link.url}}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>`

1.1 JS)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('.masonry-container').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector: '.masonry-item',
    columnWidth: '.masonry-item'
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know masonry, but angular did not render yet the template when your JS is executed.

To do what you want to do, you should instead use a **directive** and put your code inside the `link` function.

```
angular.module('Example', [])
.directive('masonry-container', [function () {
    return {
        link: function ($scope, element, attributs, controllers) {
            element.masonry({
                // ...
            });
            // ...
        }
    };
}])
```

> Directives that want to modify the DOM typically use the link option
>   to register DOM listeners as well as update the DOM. It is executed
>   after the template has been cloned and is where directive logic will
>   be put.

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Thanks a lot... I tried that, and then i found an excellent solution. https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-masonry an package that provides an directive for angular... thanks for your help...